# Calculate CRC 8 of data received on serial port c#

Tags: c#

I am receiving data from serial port in an byte array

How can I calculate the checksum of the data not included the sync (54) and checksum (F2) byte and want to match with the last check sum byte.

**Updated :**

```
int bytes = comport.BytesToRead;

            byte indexCRC;
            int sumCRC = 0;
            byte checksumCRC = 0;
            byte checksum;

            byte[] RXBuffer = new byte[bytes];


            comport.Read(RXBuffer, 0, bytes);

            checksum = RXBuffer.Last();

            byte[] RXBufferCRC = new byte[bytes];

            for (indexCRC = 1; indexCRC < RXBufferCRC.Length; indexCRC++)
            {
                sumCRC = sumCRC + RXBufferCRC[indexCRC];
            }

            checksumCRC = (byte)(sumCRC);
```

Comment: Could you perhaps give us some example of what you've tried? Maybe we can tell you why it doesn't work then.

Comment: Hi @StrahBehry I am trying something like that. Please check the question

Comment: Looks like a simple sum of bytes 1..N-2.  80 + 71 + 01 == F2.  Hard to guess what 35 might do.  Use a telephone to talk to a device programmer that knows the real answer.

Comment: @HansPassant Looks simple. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the index from 1 but before doing that delete the last index of the array and store the array in an other array something like that

```
int Secbytes = comport.BytesToRead;
byte[] SecRXBuffer = new byte[Secbytes];

Array.Copy(SecRXBuffer, VanguardConstants.RECEIVEINDEX, RXBuffer, 0, Secbytes);

byte[] tmp = new byte[bytes - 1];

Array.Copy(RXBuffer, tmp, Secbytes - 1);

for (i = 1; i < tmp.Length; i++)
{
   Sum = (byte)(Sum + tmp[i]);
}

Checksum = ((byte)Sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://err.se/crc8-for-ibutton-in-c/

Here is an implementation of a CRC8 function in C#.